# r encoding issues affect behavior of dcasting a data table

Tags: r, utf-8, data.table, dcast

I have a data table with a column that is a character vector called `nutcode`. The elements of that column have different codings. Some are `unknown` (the mac standard); some are `UTF-8`. The `UTF-8` elements include µ. An example is "vit_a_rae_µg". This encoding is probably there because the original data were read in from an Access data base using the following line of code (note encoding choice.

```
con <- odbcConnect("nutrientDataSR28",DBMSencoding="Windows-1252")
```

When I convert my data table to wide with `nutcode` providing the column names, the UTF-8 elements are not converted to columns and there is no warning message. I'm using data.table v1.9.7 on a mac (R version is Microsoft Open R ver 3.3.1.

Here's the code that has this behavior.

```
formula.wide <- paste("usda_code + IMPACT_code + FdGrp_Cd + Long_Desc + Ref_Desc + Refuse ~ nutCode")
dt.wide <- data.table::dcast(
  data = dt,
  formula = formula.wide,
  value.var = "Nutr_Val")
```

I have at least one solution, which I'll add as an answer. But I also wanted to flag this for the data.table developers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is to use the following line of code

```
Encoding(dt$nutCode) <- "unknown"
```

Update

I have since switched to

```
Encoding(dt$nutCode) <- "UTF-8"
```